# Secure User Registration with ReactJS and Django REST

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, registration

I am creating a project with React and Django REST framework,

I want to know how can I register a user through React UI in a secure way.

Do I send an HTTP request to Django with the clean password? 
this just seems **very** insecure and vulnerable

Comment: You can use https and hash the password in django and save the hashed password in your db.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on how to do it with `django-rest-auth` and `django-allauth`: https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-user-authentication-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

To register a user from a react app, you can use [django-graphql-auth](https://github.com/pedrobern/django-graphql-auth/).

It is great with react because if you want to use [relay](https://relay.dev/), it is fully compatible.

The registration process is made by sending the following graphql mutation to the server:

```
mutation {
  register(
    email:"someemail@email.com",
    username:"someusername",
    password1: "somepassword",
    password2:"somepassword"
  ) {
    success,
    errors,
    token,
    refreshToken
  }
}
```

You don't need to clean the password, as the it will be handled by django, for example, on a bad request would return something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "register": {
      "success": false,
      "errors": {
        "password2": [
          {
            "message": "This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.",
            "code": "password_too_short"
          },
          {
            "message": "This password is too common.",
            "code": "password_too_common"
          },
          {
            "message": "This password is entirely numeric.",
            "code": "password_entirely_numeric"
          }
        ]
      },
      "token": null,
      "refreshToken": null
    }
  }
}
```

The [docs](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) have more examples.

(I'm the author)